# Pass array data from CollectionView to next ViewController

Tags: viewcontroller, collectionview, swift4.2

I am developing IOS apps and I would like pass food image and title to next ViewController. Food image and title are retrieved from API and stored in array and use SDWebImage to display food image and title.
The food image and title are used public var foodTitle = String and public var foodImage = String.

Is it possible to pass the clicked image data from collection view cell to next ViewController?

I tried to use below code but it still failed to show the image and title on ViewController.

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath){

    let mainStoryboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let placeOrder = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PlaceOrderViewController") as! PlaceOrderViewController
    placeOrder.name = self.foodTitle[indexPath.item]
    placeOrder.image = self.foodImage[indexPath.row]
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(placeOrder, animated: true)
}
```

Below is the code of collection view:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MainPageCollectionViewCell
cell.FoodTitle.text = self.foodTitle[indexPath.item]
cell.Food.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: foodImage[indexPath.row]),placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "image"))
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Apparently, you are passing image URL to PlaceOrderViewController.

Answer (score 0):

As you are passing the image URL and Title, it is possible. Create an image view in the next viewController and load image of image view by SDWebImage async call.